# Helm/Projectile outside a project

Tags: helm, projectile, helm-projectile, helm-sources, helm-for-files

I use the packages Helm and helm-projectile for navigating in Emacs. I ran into problems, when I use projectile-helm inside Helm, and I'm able to reproduce this with a empty Emacs init file. The configuration to reproduce this:

```
;; Get MELPA
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "http://melpa-stable.milkbox.net/packages/") t)

;; Add Use-package to the list
(setq package-list
    '(use-package))

;; Install use-package
; activate all the packages
(package-initialize)

(use-package projectile
  :ensure t
  :diminish projectile-mode
  :config
  (projectile-global-mode) 

(use-package helm-projectile
  :ensure t
  :config
  (projectile-global-mode) 
  (helm-projectile-on))

(use-package helm
  :ensure t
  :commands helm-for-files
  :diminish helm-mode
  :config
  (helm-mode 1)
  (setq helm-for-files-preferred-list '(helm-source-recentf
                                        helm-source-projectile-files-list
                                        helm-source-projectile-recentf-list))
```

What will the problem be?

The directory `foo` contains two files:
`foo.txt` and `.git`.

The directory `bar` contains one files:
`bar.txt`.

When you're opening a file in directory `foo`:

```
foo/foo.txt
```

Then call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `helm-find-files`, the Helm window will show up, because it's a project file (because of the .git init file, so it can find files), so the source `projectile-files-list` will deliver the files.

But when you opening `bar.txt` in directory `bar`, then call <kbd>M-x</kbd> `helm-find-files`, it will not show up because it's probably still waiting on input from
    `helm-source-projectile-files-list`, in `buffers *warnings*`, or in buffer *errors* I can't find anything. I understand where this problem might come, but how could I tell Emacs, to not use `helm-source-projectile-files-list` when the buffer is currently not in a project (.git)?

Comment: Did you already see https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6ogkp3/how_to_add_more_source_to_helmfindfiles_or/? That is just a wild guess. I don't use helm.

Comment: Hi Tobias, I looked into that Reddit thread you have linked. But I found no solution/related reply to my issue, but thanks for your contribution anyway! :).

Comment: `helm-for-files` is a different command then `helm-find-files`. Are you sure you are not calling the former when you mean to be calling the the later?

Comment: @Prgm.celeritas I'm using `helm-find-files`, and not using `helm-for-files`. You might mean the setting `helm-find-files-preferred-list` based on that Reddit comment? It made no any difference in my case, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem a while ago.

Whenever files or candidate items don't appear right (in this case bar.txt) away I noticed that searching for bar.txt in the helm buffer would make it appear.

Try this.

```
(setq helm-candidate-number-limit 10000)
```

Comment: It didn't worked in my case. It makes no difference it seems. Have you tried it with the steps to reproduce this problem, without this setting and with this setting?

Comment: Without providing your entire emacs setting this is impossible to diagnose to a single misconfigured setting.